# some of excel formula change into only value with python openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, openpyxl

[image]I am doing some projects with python openpyxl. In the excel file, some of the parts should be input excel function and the other parts should be input only value, so I cannot 'data_only = True'

```
wb = load_workbook(merged_excel_file)
ws = wb.active  

last_row = ws.max_row

for o in range(5, last_row + 1):
    ws.cell(row=o, column=17).value = f"=if(countif($B$5:B{o},B{o}) = 1,3000,"'0'")"
```

Is there anything else that I can change the excel function into only values except for 'data_only = True' Because other cells should be shown by the data formula? This is my codding as followed.

Comment: Can you give an example of the excel output - I don't understand "so I cannot 'data_only = True'" too.

Comment: I added the image that I want to get results. O and Q columns should be input valuss, and P and R columns should be input into formula type. But now, O and Q column have formula type. O column is "=if(countif($B$5:B{o},B{o}) = 1,3000,"'0'")",  and Q column is "=VLOOKUP(S{r},$T{r}:$U${20000},2,FALSE)"